# Why are these loops not executed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I am experimenting with booleans to get a better understanding of them.
My book says that any empty type of data is interpreted as "False", and any non-empty type of data is interpreted as "True". When I wrote the following program, I thought I would get an infinite loop, but the program returned nothing.

```
def main():
    while False == "":
        print("i")

main()
```

I also tried

```
def main():
    while True == "b":
        print("i")

main()
```

I also expected this to be an infinite loop, but it returned nothing

Comment: `True` is not equal to `"b"` and `False` is not equal to empty string :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others are saying, `''` may be taken as a false predicate (a "falsey" value) but isn't actually `False`, and a non-empty string is truthy but not actually `True`.

But don't try it with `if False == 0:` or you will indeed get an infinite loop, as the `bool` data type is a subclass of the `int` data type. You can even do math with `True` and `False` instead of `1` and `0` if you like.

Answer (score 4):

`True` is a boolean, `"b"` is a string. They are not equal.

However, `"b"` is "truthy"

```
>>>bool("b")
True
```

This is why you can do the following if you desire an infinite loop:

```
while "my not empty string that is truthy":
    do.something()

# This is the same as:
while True:
    do.something()
```

You can also take advantage of the name's "truthiness" in if-statements:

```
if "b": # "b" is 'truthy'
    print 'this will be printed'

if "": # "" is not 'truthy'
    print 'this will not be printed'
```

This is true for other types as well:

```
if ['non-empty', 'list']: # Truthy
if []: # Falsey
if {'not' : 'empty dict'}: # Truthy
if {}: # Falsey
```

Be careful with integers. Boolean subclasses `int`. 0 is not truthy:

```
if 1:
    print 'this will print'
if 0:
    print 'this will not print'
```

Comment: So python interprets data values as booleans only when they are part of decision making structures or when you explicitly use the bool function?

Comment: Sort of. Its not exactly "interpreted" as a boolean, its more that the condition is satisfied. So,  if you have `if <condition>`, `condition` is satisfied (truthy) if it is non-empty, or non-zero in the case of numeric types. `bool(name)` *returns* an actual boolean.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that "an empty value is treated as `False`", that does not mean that `False == ""` is a true expression. What that means is the following would be an infinite loop:

```
while "b":
    print("i")
```

Answer (score 2):

The implicit truthiness of an object does not mean it will compare equally to the `True` and `False` literals.

```
>>> False == ""
False
>>> True == "b"
False
```

It just means they have a conversion (implicit or explicit) to `bool`

```
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool("b")
True
```

Which means you can use the implicit truthiness of an object in the context of `if` statements, `any`/`all`, etc.

```
if "b":
```

Or

```
while "b":
```